# Alchemy C# Websocket handshake

Tags: c#, websocket, node-webkit, alchemy

I use Alchemy in C# for a websocket server. Both Firefox and chrome can connect to the server. But NodeWekit gives a error (it is the same page).

In nodewebkit I get "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:7980/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response"

I have no clue what to do now. Does someone has a idea? of a better C# server lib?

Thanks already!

Comment: It looks more like a node-webkit issue rather than an Alchemy issue. Try to connect to some example like wss://echo.websocket.org and see if you get your inputs echoed.

Comment: I have successfully used web-sockets in my C# application with nwjs. I used  WebSocketSharp library.